# installing ubuntu and starting windows isn't in boot option

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive, boot

I didn't installing ubuntu alongside my windows7.

I have windows7 installed in my ssd and ubuntu in another. Right before I install ubuntu, I unplugged all my other hdd. 1st because it the ubuntu installation somehow didn't detect the hdd I want to install onto and 2nd because in that way I would be I didn't choose the wrong hdd to install ubuntu onto.

After ubuntu install is completed and running, I plugged my windows7 hdd and other storage hdd back.

But somehow when I restart my pc, it didn't even ask which os to use it just directly goes into ubuntu. I used F12 to have the option to select device to boot up with and I can clearly see my windows7 ssh and of course by clicking it, windows7 boots up properly.

I went into my bios and check my boot priority and options. There are only two boot options and the first is my ubuntu hdd and second is my optic drive. When I try to change the boot option, those two are the only options I can choose from. I cannot choose from any other hdd.

Can someone give me a hand?

Thanks in advance people.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sudo update-grub` in Ubuntu, then Windows 7 should be available in grub!

Comment: finally understand what the grub does, it creates a small menu right? But is there a way to customize that menu?

Comment: Yes, it's fully customize-able.

Comment: how can I customize it? :(

Comment: Depends on what you want customized, but here is a youtube video for chancing colors and put a custom background: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ijPb8f7oVXU

Comment: thanks thanks, getting understandable how things work.
not sure if you can answer this, if you can it'll be great so I don't have to open another thread.

Comment: how / what should I do so that if windows is the hdd running automatically but able to find the ubuntu boot start up?
my understanding now about grub is IF my hdd is originally installed with ubuntu then the grub will help me find windows boot but if I set windows to boot as original windows wouldn't be able to detect ubuntu